# Determining whether the sum of x numbers in a sequence is less than y

Tags: c++, c

How can I check if two numbers from a sequence are lower than 5?

The function needs to get a sequence and check if a sum of any of the numbers are smaller than 5. I'm having truble to figure how I can get the first two values because at first there is always one.

```
int check_if_under_5(int Knum)
{
    int sequence=0, Anum=0, Bnum=0;
    printf("Enter a sequence. To stop print, enter -1\n");
    while(sequence != -1)
    {
        Anum = sequence;
        scanf("%d",&sequence);
        Bnum = sequence;
        if (Anum + Bnum < 5)
            return 1;
        else
            sequence = Anum;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Knum`?

Comment: You never use it in your function. You've hardcoded the value 5 into your algorithm (and your function name).

Comment: yes i know it was only for the example here on the forum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Scan the sequence keeping track of the smallest element seen so far.
- For each new element check if `smallest_so_far + new_element < 5`. If so, return true.
- Otherwise update `smallest_so_far` if necessary and continue with the next element.
- If you reach the end of the sequence without returning true, then return false.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize sequence with Knum+1 not with 0.